# Transpose tbl_summary output

Tags: r, gtsummary

I note a similar request from some time ago [tbl_summary ( gtsummary) transpose with p-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64667366/tbl-summary-gtsummary-transpose-with-p-values) but it has not helped solve my issue.

Is there a way to to manipulate the output of `tbl_summary` such that columns become rows and row become columns.

My sample code is structured as such:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(
  x=sample(1:4),
  y=sample(1:4),
  z=sample(1:4),
  time=runif(200, min=2, max=25))
a1 <- tbl_summary(dat %>% select(c(time, x)), by=x ,
                  label=list(time ~ "Follow-up time (Group 1)"),
                  statistic = list(all_continuous()~ "{median} ({p25}, {p75})")) 
a2 <- tbl_summary(dat %>% select(c(time, y)), by=y ,
                  label=list(time ~ "Follow-up time (Group 2)"),
                  statistic = list(all_continuous()~ "{median} ({p25}, {p75})")) 
a3 <- tbl_summary(dat %>% select(c(time, z)), by=z,
                  label=list(time ~ "Follow-up time (Group 3)"),
                  statistic = list(all_continuous()~ "{median} ({p25}, {p75})")) 
tbl_stack(list(a1,a2,a3))
```

Here I am using `by=` to get `tbl_summary` to quickly compute the median and 95%CI per 'group'. However, I am interested in having 'x', 'y', and 'z' as the columns and the levels of each group as the rows.

Sample output [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you've got looks great. I would make the following modification so you don't have any repeated code.

```r
map(
  c("x", "y", "z"),
  ~ tbl_summary(
      dat,
      by = all_of(.x),
      include = time,
      label = list(time = .x)
    )
) %>%
  tbl_stack()
```

There is a function to get you *similar* tables, but not an perfect match for your situation. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_continuous.html

Comment: Thanks @Daniel I appreciate the modified code. For the link, I guess to use `tbl_continuous` for my purpose, it relies on the the 'time' variable being computed for all  the different groups as separate vectors so I'm back to square one! Is there no way to transpose the columns as rows in a `tbl_summary` output. In my example above, the columns would "Follow up (Group 1) - Follow up (Group 2) - Follow up (Group 3)" and then the rows would be "1 - 2 - 3 - 4", namely the levels of the grouping vectors.

Comment: A gtsummary table cannot be transposed because the underlying data structure won't allow for the transpose AND apply the formatting correctly. We can, however, construct tables in a transposed way, like we've done above. We also added a similar function (but for categorical data, not continuous)...perhaps a continuous variant is warrented?
http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/bstfun/reference/tbl_likert.html

http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/bstfun/reference/tbl_likert.html