# How can I transpose a gtsummary tbl_summary object?

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape, gtsummary

In my hypothetical scenario, 100 people are asked: What is your favorite color of car, shirt, and website (red, blue, or yellow)? This yields my mock data frame:

```
colors <- c("red", "blue", "yellow")
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:100, 
car = sample(colors, 100, replace=TRUE), 
shirt = sample(colors, 100, replace=TRUE), 
website = sample(colors, 100, replace=TRUE)
)
```

I can make a nice summary table from gtsummary:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

tbl_summary(df, include = c(car, shirt, website))
```

[image]

I would like to transpose this table data so the result has three rows (car, shirt, and website) and three columns (blue, red, and yellow), as in:

```
                # blue  red  yellow 
# Characteristic
car  39 (39%) 40 (40%) 21 (21%)
shirt 39 (39%) 35 (35%) 26 (26%)
website 35 (35%) 32 (32%) 33 (33%)
```

I tried a script which analyzes a continuous variable from: [Transpose tbl_summary output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69731678/transpose-tbl-summary-output)
but the result is not what I want.

```
map(
  c("car", "shirt", "website"),
  ~ tbl_summary(
    df,
    by = all_of(.x),
    include = c(car, shirt, website)
  )
) %>%
  tbl_stack()
```

[image]

Any advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function in the bstfun package that does just what you need, and it's a gtsummary extension.
https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/bstfun/reference/tbl_likert.html

```r
colors <- c("red", "blue", "yellow")
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100, 
  car = sample(colors, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  shirt = sample(colors, 100, replace=TRUE), 
  website = sample(colors, 100, replace=TRUE)
)

df |> 
  bstfun::tbl_likert(include = c(car, shirt, website)) |> 
  gtsummary::as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **blue** | **red** | **yellow** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car | 39 (39%) | 40 (40%) | 21 (21%) |
| shirt | 39 (39%) | 35 (35%) | 26 (26%) |
| website | 35 (35%) | 32 (32%) | 33 (33%) |

<sup>Created on 2023-12-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your data first from wide to long which makes it easy to produce your desired output

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

colors <- c("red", "blue", "yellow")
set.seed(42)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(id      = seq_len(n),
                 car     = sample(colors, n, replace = TRUE),
                 shirt   = sample(colors, n, replace = TRUE),
                 website = sample(colors, n, replace = TRUE))

# into long format
dt_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df,
                               cols      = c("car", "shirt", "website"),
                               names_to  = "object",
                               values_to = "color")

# desired outcome - specified via the `by` argument
tbl_summary(dt_long,
            include = c(object, color),
            by      = color)
```

[image]