Categorical variables instead of columns needs to be rows using gtsummary
Summary statistics in a paper
I want my table similar to this one from the academic paper, but i have an issue displaying the car marks in rows instead of columns. So far my table shows the car marks on the columns instead of rows so if someone could help me out to transpose it would be perfect!
list("style_number-arg:big.mark" = "") %>%
  set_gtsummary_theme()

df_selected <- df %>%
  select(mark, price, year, mileage, vol_engine, fuel)

gts_stat1 <- tbl_summary(
  data = df_selected,
  by = mark,
  statistic = list(
    all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
    all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
  label = list(price ~ "Price", year ~ "Build Year", mileage ~ "Mileage", vol_engine ~ "Volume Engine", fuel ~ "Fuel"),
  digits = list(year ~ c(0, 1)),
  missing = "no"
) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "**Car Marks**"
  ) %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "Mean and Standard Deviation are presented in parentheses. The variable 'Fuel' is separated into different fuel types, and the proportion per fuel type is shown for each mark") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  italicize_levels() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_header(title = gt::md("**Summary Statistics**")) %>%
  #gt::gtsave(filename = "summary_statistics.ltx")

print(gts_stat1)

I want my column which are the car marks to be rows instead of columns, this is my code so far:

It's really hard to help you without a sample of your data. For selective transposing, I suggest pivot_longer() and pivot_wider() from the tidyr package.

Does this post help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69731678/transpose-tbl-summary-output

Have encountered myself wanting to do something similar and found it easier to use gtsummary as it comes as it makes post-hoc customisation alot easier.
I am still looking for a better way myself...
Roughly:
Give demo data:
  df <- tibble(
    mark = sample(rep(c("Toyota", "Honda", "Ford", "Chevrolet", "Toyota"),10),20),
    price = sample(rep(c(25000, 27000, 22000, 23000, 26000),10), 20),
    year = sample(rep(c(2018, 2017, 2019, 2016, 2018),10), 20),
    mileage = sample(rep(c(30000, 35000, 20000, 40000, 28000), 10), 20),
    vol_engine = sample(rep(c(2.5, 2.0, 1.8, 2.2, 2.4),10),20),
    fuel = sample(rep(c(400, 450 , 225, 800, 230),10),20)
  )

Store your vars in an object
include_vars<- c( "price", "year", "mileage", "vol_engine", "fuel") # exclude "mark"

Create your custom summary function (you'll have to include your own one for standard deviation etc.)
  my_stats <- function(data, ...) {
    mean_price <- mean(data$price, na.rm = TRUE)
    mean_year <- mean(data$year, na.rm = TRUE)
    mean_mileage <- mean(data$mileage, na.rm = TRUE)
    mean_vol_engine <- mean(data$vol_engine, na.rm = TRUE)
    mean_fuel <- mean(data$fuel, na.rm = TRUE)
    dplyr::tibble(
      mean_price = mean_price,
      mean_year = mean_year,
      mean_mileage = mean_mileage,
      mean_vol_engine = mean_vol_engine,
      mean_fuel = mean_fuel
    )
  }

Loop each table and store in a list to pass to tbl_merge later.
merging<-list()

for( i in include_vars){
  merging[[i]]<- df_selected %>%
    tbl_custom_summary(
      include = c("mark"),
      stat_fns = everything() ~ my_stats,
      statistic = everything() ~ paste0("{mean_",i,"}")
    ) 
}

Merge tbls in your list
  tbl_merge(tbls = merging, tab_spanner = paste0("**", include_vars, "**"))

This will still require some customisation which can get a bit finicky and additional stats (like sd).
This code also assumes that ALL your vars are continuous. Any categorical will give NA.
